# Normal build and run successful, but archive build failed

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I used DKChainableAnimationKit framework for the UIView animation. It succeeded in the normal build but when I tried to archive the project it showed the issues mentioned below.

[image]

I added the framework to build phases and I import the DKChainableAnimationKit framework.

But I get the error while I archive. I don't know why the error has happened.

[image]

Comment: What's the Scheme for archiving? What configuration does it use? Anything odd about that configuration? What are the build settings for that configuration? Are you using Whole Module Optimization, and does it help if you change that?

Comment: its because of wrong search path in project setting , check once

Comment: what is the solution for that?

Comment: I tried above-mentioned step but still, I have an error in archiving the project.if any knows the answer to this error.ping me, friends. thanks in advance